# My linked lists program terminated with status -1073741819 In Code blocks compiler(x0000000005))

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime-error

**Here is the Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
typedef node *list;

bool create(list header){
    return header==NULL;
}

void insert_begining(list header,int item){
    node*p;
    p=new(node);
    if (p=NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    p->data=item;
    p->next=header;
    header=p;
}

void insert_end(list header,int item){
    list p,q;
    p=new(node);
    p->data=item;
    p->next=NULL;
    if (header==NULL)
    {
        header=p;
    }
    else
    {
        q=header;
        while(q->next!=NULL){
            q=q->next;

        }
        q->next=p;
    }

}

void print_list(list header){
    node* p;
    p=header;
    while(p->next!=NULL){
        cout<<p->data<<endl;
        p=p->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    list header;
    create(header);
    insert_end(header,500);
    insert_end(header,600);
    insert_end(header,4);
    insert_end(header,6);
    print_list(header);
    return 0;
}
```

i run the program and it shows

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 6.720 s

i really don't know why.I think that the syntax is right
pleases check the program above and tell me what to do.
i am a beginner and i really don't know much about linked lists

Comment: 1) `if (p=NULL)` --> `if (p==NULL)` 2) `header=p;` not change caller side variable. 3) `list header;` : `header` isn't initialized.

Comment: _i am a beginner and i really don't know much about linked lists_ - it will be hard to write a code without understanding what you are writing for. Please read on link list. There's plenty available if you search google. For the specific error you are getting, @BLUEPIXY pointed it out.

Comment: You are passing the `header` param by value, so whenever you think you are assigning to it, you actually are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference. In the former case a **copy** of the var is passed and in the latter the actual var is passed. Ex:

```
void f1(int x) {   // Pass by value
    x = 1;
}
void f2(int& x) {  // Pass by reference
    x = 2;
}
int main() {
    int y = 0;
    f1(y);
    // y is still 0
    f2(y);
    // y is now 2
}
```

In your program, you pass `header` by value:

```
void insert_begining(list header,int item){
    // ....
    header=p;    // Only modifying the local var!
}
```

Some things I would do:
First, get rid of that typedef. This is C++ but you are not using classes, so I assume you haven't learned them yet. Instead, create a linked list struct:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
struct linked_list {
    struct node *head;
    linked_list() : head(nullptr) {}  // ctor
};
```

No more typedef needed, and now you can easily pass by reference. Ex:

```
void insert_begining(linked_list& list, int item){
    // removed for brevity
    p->next = list.head;
    list.head = p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the header variable it is not initialized to NULL. In C++ 
variables are usually not initialized by the compiler upon declaration.

So when you make the call

```
insert_end(header, 500);
```

inside the function the else block is executed since header is not NULL but a garbage value. The culprit here is:

```
 while(q->next!=NULL);
```

You cannot evaluate **q->next** since q points to a random memory location and hence the segfault. You need to assign to a variable before accessing it.

So in you main function add this:

```
list header = NULL;
```

Apart for this your might want to check BLUPIX's comments about other problems. 
Also use nullptr instead of NULL if the compiler supports C++11